# Can one legally use force to stop someone from damaging their property?

Tags: property, self-defense, washington

Alice is throwing rocks through Bob's house's windows. Bob asks Alice to stop, but she ignores him, and continues.

Is Bob legally allowed to use force to make Alice stop damaging his property?

Specifically interested in Seattle, WA, USA.